# Adding a Forum to my Nodejs Webapp

Tags: node.js, forum, nodebb

I have a HapiJS Node web application **example.com** currently running. I wish to add a forum to build a community on my website at the url **example.com/community**

Till now I've looked at [NodeBB](https://github.com/NodeBB/NodeBB). It however, runs on a seperate node server of its own and i'm unable to figure out how to direct it to my original domain (example.com)

Comment: FYI, I removed the irrelevant _php_ tag. You should only add _relevant_ tags.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to use a reverse proxy like nginx, so that requests to `/` are sent to the HapiJS app, and requests to `/community` are sent to NodeBB.

*Relevant sections in nginx config*

```
location / {
  .. do whatever
}

location /forum/ {
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;

    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:4567;
    proxy_redirect off;

    # Socket.IO Support
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
}
```